# How to open a div element, along with its value in a newtab using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I haven't started anything but is this possible?
My desired output would be a div element containing a background image and if I click the DIV element it will open a newtab and display its values as if it is a fullscreen perspective of the DIV.

Thank you

Comment: You write the value to localStorage and than after redirect read that value.

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, may I ask if you have sources that successfully shows how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick if you don't want to use javascript.

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" target="_blank">
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" alt="house"/>
  </div>
</a>
```